# Measurable goals for a new web team/department?

Tags: web-development, website-design, goals

I'm part of a new web team (the area is new) and we have to define goals. I need to define this goals so they can be measurable maybe monthly and yearly.

So my questions is if these goals should be monetary only or quantity of websites reached, both or if there are better parameters than the ones cited?

I will be so grateful if you at least can point the right way to find them.

Comment: What do you mean by "web team"? Will your team be doing everything including running servers, design, development, and paid advertising? Or are you only doing the web development, and letting other departments handle servers (IT), design and marketing? The goals and metrics will differ depending on the scope of the department.

Comment: Thanks @nathangiesbrecht for your time. Well, we are organized in 4 divisions in our _Web Team._ **Web Design** (everything related to the art work for web) **Social Media** (everything about brands presence in social networks) **Web Development** (programming, FB Apps, etc.) and a **Creative** division to come up with all kind of ideas for the previous 3 mentioned. Did I answered your question? Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

For the design team, you'll want their goals to be related to the conversion rate on the website. It's their jobs to make the site aesthetically pleasing and easy for customers to use.

The social media team will be responsible for driving traffic to the site, so you'll likely  want to keep an eye on total traffic to the site, particularly from Social Networks (fairly easy to find in Google Analytics, as an example), and things like Facebook Like's, Twitter followers, Pinterest, etc. Facebook does have their own Insights platform, so you'd likely want to check into that as well.

The Web Development team will be responsible for the functionality of the website, so you could boil it down to something as simple uptime. But there's also important metrics like site speed which are easily measurable which they should always keep in mind when planning.

The "creative" division, which I'm sort of picturing as the Internet Marketing Management team should keep it simple and have basic ROI (return on investment) targets. If they're in charge of the overall project management, then they should be held accountable for the resources that they're managing (the team) and what the company is getting out of those resources.

Obviously this answer is subjective, but I hope it provides you with a good starting point.

Comment: And just as an aside, for the social media team, you really should hire at least one SEO person and one paid search engine marketing (SEM) person. This depends entirely on the specifics of the business plan. But having someone in house who knows proper mark-up (the developers will make it work with whatever tags they feel like) will make everything everybody else does that much better. It's a really key position if you're planning on doing any serious selling on the internet.

Answer (score 1):

There is no right answer to this question without fully knowing what is it that the business is looking at from the *web team*.

However, do go through this excellent post by Avinash Kaushik on how a business should [focus on real business profitability](http://www.kaushik.net/avinash/analytics-tip-obsess-about-real-business-profitability). Needless to say to get at this stage, you will need a web tracking system such as GA integrated with your own CRM and Accounts data. But the effort is well worth it.